# Several MySQL users in Joomla 1.5 configuration.php

Tags: php, joomla1.5

In order to solve MySQL 1226 error i follow [this](http://joomlaportal.ru/content/view/319/53/) recomendation, but it doesn't work.
I'm getting an error:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in configuration.php on line 38**

*configuration.php content:*

```
1:<?php
2:class JConfig {
.....
37:public $users = array("root", "boot", "foot");
38:public $user = $users[array_rand($users)];
.....
90:}
91:?>
```

Please help me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by adding __construct() function:

```
var $user = '';
var $users = array("root", "boot", "foot");

    public function __construct() { 
    $this->user = $this->users[mt_rand(0, count($this->users) - 1)]; 
    }
```